# Cannot get Azure DevOps connected to SonarQube on Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-virtual-machine, azure-nsg

I have a simple setup with a single Azure VM running sonarqube, and an NSG attached to the NIC with a public IP. I have been unable to get the NSG inbound rule to work with either Service Tag 'AzureDevOps' or 'AzureCloud'. Everything else in the NSG has been configured at this point to either Any or * other than the destination port 9000.

I tried multiple Service Tags and it keeps giving me the same timeout error:

##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"errno":"ETIMEDOUT","code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"","port":9000}

The only thing that works is to have it open to any source, which is no feasible anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"errno":"ETIMEDOUT","code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"","port":9000}

To solve this issue, you need to add the correct service tag to the VM NSG rule if you are using Microsoft-hosted Agent.

Refer to the following steps to confirm the service tag:

Step1: Check the Azure DevOps Organization Region in **Organization Setting -> Overview -> Region**

Step2: Based on the region ,you can go to **Azure VM -> Networking -> Find the service tag: Azurecloud.regionname**

For example:

**Region: Southeast Asia** -> **Service tag: AzureCloud.southeastasia**

[image]

On the other hand, if you are using self-hosted agent, you need to manually get the Agent IP and add to NSG rule.

Comment: Well, I believe the Source is supposed to be AzureCloud.<region>, but yes, that is what I currently have set up. I am using Microsoft hosted Azure DevOps. I have verified my region in the DevOps portal under Organization Settings. I have set the source as a Service Tag with the AzureCloud.<devops region>, and I have the destination set as any with custom port of 9000. It continues to fail with the ETIMEDOUT error. There are no other NSGs attached to the NIC or the subnet.

Comment: Can you share your organization Region? refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#to-identify-the-possible-ip-ranges-for-microsoft-hosted-agents  If your org region is west europe or Brazil South , you also need to add the backup region service tag.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  I did not realize you may have to add all the regions in the geography you are in. I thought that was only a few regions, but being in the US geography, I started adding other regions until I found the one that worked. Thanks.